# Cannot assign "8": "Comment.post" must be a "Post" instance

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I can access a post using its ID or a slugified version of its title. Both localhost:8000/post/working-in-malaysia and localhost:8000/post/8 load the post called Working in Malaysia.

I want users to be able to comment on any post. 
The comments load with the code     `comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post.id ,active=True)`

[image]
[image]

When I manually select the value for the Post field, the comments are saved to the sites database.

[image]

But I want the value for the Post field to be automatically populated. Based on the current post being displayed.

I have tried `new_comment.post = post.id` and `new_comment.post = post.title`.

[image]

[image]

**views.py**

```
if request.method == 'POST':

   comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
    if comment_form.is_valid():
      new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
      new_comment.post = post.id
      new_comment.save()


else:
    comment_form = CommentForm()
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='blog-home'),
    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'), 
    path('post/<slug:pk_slug>/', views.post_detail, name='post-detail'),
    #path('post/<slug:the_slug>/', views.post_detail, name='post-detail'),

    path('post/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='blog-about'),
    #path('your-name/', views.about2, name='blog-about'),
    path('facebook/',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='blog/index.html'), name="facebook")
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be instance of `Post` means should be post object, not an id. So:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404         // import get_object_or_404

// Post instance which will be assigned to post attribute in Comment model
post_instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post.id)

new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
new_comment.post = post_instance
new_comment.save()
```